# How long should spark take to read 500GB of data? Suggestions for perf improvement?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

It currently takes each task about 2m to read 500MB of data. Is this typical? More details below:

There are 30 executors each with 5 cores. The entire stage takes about 20 minutes overall (or 46h aggregate, or about 1.5h per executor) to read 500-600GB of data into memory. There is 12GB memory allocated per executor and it splits the job into about 1500 tasks. We filter the data down somewhat, but I assume that does not affect the read time since it needs to pull the entire dataset into memory.

Does this amount of time sound right? Are there any easy (or less-easy) improvements I can make to decrease this time (other than just linearly scaling the job). 20 minutes is a long time and we'd like to cut this down if possible. It is a batch job btw.

Comment: Where is the data stored? How are you reading it? In what format is the data written?

Comment: There is no "typical" there are so many variables. Are the data partitioned, if so how is the skew? what file format are you using (csv/parquet) what kind of compression ratios are you achieving? Filtering can effect read times depending on if/how data are partitioned.